# Adding Database support on a static website

Tags: web-development-server

i'm new in web-development and i have this website where currently i update the articles by changing my source codes.
I wanna setup a database where i can add this new articles and my website can fetch it from there so that it can reflect on my website

Point me to some right direction and let me know if my question is not clear enough?

Comment: So... you need to set up a database.  What is your question exactly?

Comment: where to start from? i know nothing about what i'm gonna need is there's any tutorial for it?

Comment: @jmargolisvt and do it have to use Javascript for fetching the data from my database?

Comment: SO is explicitly _not_ for helping people find resources or make opinionated choices.  Reddit or Quora is a better place for this question.

Comment: @jmargolisvt alright! Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad but I'll try to explain it briefly. 
For making a website with dynamic content, you need to have a database (mysql for example) which will store your articles.

You'll need to have a server (ex apache) & You'll then have to code (in PHP, Python, C# etc) which will handle a user's request. When a user open's your webpage, the request goes to your apache server, it then executes the appropriate code (an example task of a php code could be fetch articles from the database) and return a response to the user.